# Single Column Layout For Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to optimize our site for mobile and I keep running into a formatting problem. Whenever you scale the browser down to mobile size, you'll be able to see that all of the columns are offset and spaced differently. Instead, I am looking to align all of these elements in a neat column when mobile settings are activated.

Please note: I am only trying to accomplish this for Mobile. I am happy with our tablet mode and desktop mode.

We are using Visual Composer and Go Pricing as plugins.

Here is the code I used to align our pricing tables for desktop format:

```
<div style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">[go_pricing id="multicam_productions"]</div>
```

Here is our website: http://visualicreative.com/conference/

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about: http://visualicreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Screen-Shot-2014-11-21-at-9.44.52-AM.png

Comment: Did you solve your alignment problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your "What Service" div has a `.vc_custom_1410664290855` class on it with `margin-left: 10% !important;` which is causing the offset in your screenshot.

Remove that margin with a media query at the appropriate size.